# Add trim method to setter in Lombok

Tags: java, setter, lombok

I use Project Lombok for generate the getter/setter for String field. This field, for example password, has validation annotation.

```
@Size(min = 6,max = 100, message = "The password must be between 6 and 100 characters") 
private String password;
```

I wanna add trim method in the setter for not counting white space in the length.

```
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password.trim();
}
```

How can I add trim method in Lombok setter? Or I must write custom setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you would have to write a custom setter. If you were using the Immutable equivalent (Wither), you could put the trim() inside the constructor and just add [@Wither](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Wither.html) to the method, and this would also hold for builders generated via [@Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html) also. It's a safer approach, that ensures the password will always be trimmed.

```
  @Wither
  @Size(min = 6,max = 100, message = "The password must be between 6 and 100 characters") 
  private final String password; //guaranteed to be trimmed


  public MyClass(final String password){  
    this.password=  password.trim();
  }
```

Update:

> @Wither was introduced as experimental feature in lombok v0.11.4.
> @Wither was renamed to @With, and moved out of experimental and into the core package, in lombok v1.18.10.

From the aboce link to Wither.